Set Jetty workerName in Spring Boot 3.x
I'm approaching an application which relies on Jetty to serve responses as an embedded Spring Boot server.
For serving with sticky session I need to set the node name that is appended to the JSESSIONID cookie.
From what I could find, if it were a standard Jetty deployment we would have to set the property jetty.sessionIdManager.workerName. In Spring Boot, however this doesn't seem to be the case. I tried any kind of Spring-Boot-like kind of property (like server.jetty.sessionIdManager.workerName, server.jetty.sessionIdManager.workerName, server.jetty.session-id-manager.worker-name) but nothing worked.
Does anyone know the answer?
I expected to have workerName=foo and therefore JSESSIONID=.foo.

It might not be something you do with properties as such property with name "worker" is listed on Spring Boot properties appendix for Jetty (search for jetty on that page) https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/appendix/application-properties/index.html I don't know the solution myself but it might help you direct your research in another direction.

@JorgeCampos I actually found the answer myself not in the Spring Boot documentation but in the Jetty documentation. Here https://jetty.org/docs/jetty/12/operations-guide/session/index.html#configuration it says that the node name is set by either configuring the $JETTY_BASE/start.d/sessions.ini file (which cannot be done here, being a Spring Boot deployment) or by setting the environment variable JETTY_WORKER_INSTANCE, which fits the most the kind of deployment I'm using.

Awesome! You should add that as an answer then!
